# set focus() on ref with v-for and Typescript

Tags: vue.js

My goal is when the **button** is clicked, the **button** is hidden, and the corresponding **input** is displayed and *focused*.

```
let tagIdBeingEdited = ref(0)
let buttons = ref([])
let inputs = ref([])

async function toggleTagInput(id:number, index:number ) {

    tagIdBeingEdited.value = id

    //this does not work
    let a = inputs.value[index] as HTMLInputElement
    nextTick()
    a.focus()
    
}
<div v-for="tag,index in props.tags" :key="tag.id">
            <button v-show="tagIdBeingEdited !== tag.id"  
                    @click="toggleTagInput(tag.id,index)"
                    ref="buttons">{{tag.name}}</button> 

            <input  v-show="tagIdBeingEdited == tag.id"      //show input
                    @keyup.enter="changeTagName"     //change data
                    @keydown.esc="tagIdBeingEdited=0"        //hide input
                    ref="inputs"
```

If I try `inputs.value[index].focus()` Typescript says `Property 'focus' does not exist on type 'never'`

I've spent hours on this, should I just use document.getElementById('').focus()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just missing an `await` before [`nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/api/general.html#nexttick) which is an asynchronous function.

```js
let a = inputs.value[index] as HTMLInputElement
await nextTick()
a.focus()
```

I'm guessing `inputs.value[index].focus()` was attempted separately since it's not part of your snippet? TypeScript doesn't know what type `inputs.value[index]` is before you have a chance to cast it. Just keep your code like you have it in your snippet where you cast first *then* you focus.

Alternatively, you can provide the type information of `inputs` when you first define it.

```js
let inputs = ref<HTMLInputElement[]>([])
```

Then `inputs.value[index].focus()` actually will work.

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: ref<HTMLInputElement[]>([]) this was the alpha code that made the difference and await nextTick() was also essential. Thanks so much!